# xcode new class that inherits from UIView does not create a XIB file

Tags: xcode

I'm creating a new class that inherits from UIView. I remember that xcode 3 had a checkbox with the option to create an XIB attached to that class but I don't see it in xcode 4.
I go through with the dialog and all I end up with is my new class (.h and .m files) but not xib.

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks,
Daniel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to enter a class to subclass that supports a xib:

[image]

Otherwise the checkbox is disabled:
[image]